# How to Add a new version of java rest API - Springboot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

How shall i add a new version of my controller class in rest api?
here is my scenario.

My current rest api version is set in application.properties like below

```
server.contextPath=/my_rest_api/v1
```

we are using springfox for the swagger ui. the swagger api docs path is mentioned in same application.properties as below

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api-docs
```

few controllers are created and Mapped for example `@RequestMapping("/address")`

I am able to access the address controller using the url `/my_rest_api/v1/address`
and api-docs are accessible under the url `'/my_rest_api/v1/api-docs'.`

Now i have few modifications required in the existing address controller. for backward compatibility i need to keep the current version also.
So the plan is to create a version 2 of the rest api. What is the best approach to do this.

I was thinking to create new version of address controller with `@RequestMapping("/v2/address")` , change the current address controller to `@RequestMapping("/v1/address")` and remove version from the server context like this `server.contextPath=/my_rest_api/` . 
Is this a right approach?? If No please advice. if this way is ok. how shall i set the `springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api-docs` for each version?. Very new to this.. any help is appreciated.